# Настройка vlan trunk

Tags: kvm, vlan, bridge

Добрый день!

Помогите с настройкой сетевого интерфейса в linux (в данном случае debian)

Имеется один интерфейс eth0, к нему идет trunk с кучей vlan
Необходимо разбить его так чтоб на одном из виртуальных интерфесов был допустим vlan1 c dhcp а на втором проходил транк необходимый для виртуальных машин в kvm.

Вот что то в этом роде (/etc/network/interfaces)

```
auto eth0.1
iface eth0.1 inet dhcp
 vlan_raw_device eth0

 auto eth0.allvlans
iface eth0.allvlans inet manual
 vlan_raw_device eth0
```

open vswitch не предлагать.
Почему нужен trunk ? - потому что на kvm будет стоять vsrx

Comment: на хосте не нужно поднимать все вланы

Comment: необходимо для vsrx

Comment: глупости. отдаешь eth через mactap в виртуалку и там уже поднимай нужные вланы